# Android how to get the wifi downloading and uploading speed for every minute ?

Tags: android, android-wifi

I want to get the wifi both downloading and uploading speed. but i wont do any background works. i want to know using wifi signal level or rssi value. .

Please advice me to get it .

Thanks,
Rajesh K

Comment: you can't get download speed, you can calculate it.

Comment: @mihail can you tel me how to ?

Comment: well, the download speed should be calculated/displayed through some interval. For example in every second - you divide the downloaded size by the time elapsed. But I'm not really familiar how to get this data while android is downloading.

Comment: any code example, link ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the only way to get download / upload speed is to download / upload something.  You cannot calculate it from signal level or similar.  This is mainly due to throughput being affected by a lot more than just signal strength (e.g. how busy is the wifi router, how fast is its net connection, how fast is the server, how fast is every component between the wifi router and the server, etc)

In short - you'll have to download / upload something (preferably something big enough that that you can average several readings to get an accurate result)

Edit: if you are wanting the theoretical speed of the wifi connection (e.g. the nominal speed for an a/b/g/n type connection) then I'm not sure - I don't think there was a standard interface for getting the connection mode from the wifi...